# In the LinkedIn API, what is eyebrowUrl?

Tags: linkedin-api

In this section of LinkedIn's API documentation ["*Get a company's updates*"](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#company_updates), it shows that the API response has a field named **eyebrowUrl**. In some places it is also eyebrow-url.

What is this eyebrow url field and why is it called eyebrowUrl?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that it is a reference to where the url may appear with a post, similar in appearance to an eyebrow on a person's face. That is, to show something at the top of a post, aligned to one side, and in a horizontal shape.